# Alignement of image with table row

Tags: html

I am having problems with a cell in my table, one row table for now, that contains an image. Whenever I put the image inside the cell, the row automatically goes from the top of the table to the center. I tried using v align in the row but the other content ends up looking stupid. Help please. Also I made sure the cell is bigger than the image by sizing down the image. Please help.

Thank you

```
<table width="710" bgcolor="white" height="600" align="center" cellpadding="10">
    <tr>
        <td width="100" height="150" align="center" valign="top">Home</td>
        <td width="100" height="150" align="center">Food</td>
        <td width="100" height="150" align="center">Hobbies</td>
        <td width="100" height="150" align="center">Martin's Blog</td>
        <td width="300" height="150" colspan="2" valign="top"><img src="yooo.gif" width="250"></td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="450">   </td>   </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to note.

you should close your `<img>` tags like so:

```
<img src="yooo.gif" width="250" />
```

note the `/` at the end of the tag.

**EDIT** 
Apologies, the `<img>` tag only needs to be closed when using XHTML. [Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp)

Secondly the `<tr>` is the row tag not the `<td>` tag. You've only applied `valign="top"` to one of your cells. If you want the rest of the cells in that row to be aligned top you need to add the `valign` to each cell.

Fiddle example here: http://jsfiddle.net/6E66m/

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I will use valign for the whole row, and make the cellpadding at the top larger

Answer (score 1):

Add to the 2nd row same amount of TD or use colspan. `valign="top"` works ok.